# Dri3 and Present extension on client application

Tags: rendering, x11, xserver, pixmap

I am looking for someone who has experience/knowledge on how to implement dri3 and present extension in client application.

My use case will be:
I have a dma buffer generated at my application and want to use present extension to render it to screen.

Comment: Tried to look for example online but hardly to find one.

Comment: Right now the question is unclear.  To avoid having it flagged for closure, you should show what you have tried so far and narrow the focus of the question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sharvil111 and Grey for the prompt response.
I found a present test from xf86-intel-driver - test/present-test.c. I ported the below code to my app. I am getting a black screen at the end. I would expect the pixmap created is empty and therefore a black screen is expected.

Correct me if I am wrong.

```
static int test_dri3(Display *dpy)
{
    Window win = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);
    Pixmap pixmap;
    Window root;
    unsigned int width, height;
    unsigned border, depth;
    unsigned stride, size;
    int x, y, ret = 1;
    int device, handle;
    int bpp;

    device = dri3_open(dpy);
    if (device < 0)
            return 0;

    if (!is_intel(device))
            return 0;

    printf("Opened Intel DRI3 device\n");

    XGetGeometry(dpy, win, &root, &x, &y,
                 &width, &height, &border, &depth);

    switch (depth) {
    case 8: bpp = 8; break;
    case 15: case 16: bpp = 16; break;
    case 24: case 32: bpp = 32; break;
    default: return 0;
    }

    stride = width * bpp/8;
    size = PAGE_ALIGN(stride * height);
    printf("Creating DRI3 %dx%d (source stride=%d, size=%d) for GTT\n",
           width, height, stride, size);

    pixmap = 0;
    handle = gem_create(device, size);
    if (handle) {
            pixmap = dri3_create_pixmap(dpy, root,
                                         width, height, depth,
                                         gem_export(device, handle), bpp, stride, size);
            gem_close(device, handle);
    }
    if (pixmap == 0)
            goto fail;

    xcb_present_pixmap(XGetXCBConnection(dpy),
                       win, pixmap,
                       0, /* sbc */
                       0, /* valid */
                       0, /* update */
                       0, /* x_off */
                       0, /* y_off */
                       None,
                       None, /* wait fence */
                       None,
                       XCB_PRESENT_OPTION_NONE,
                       0, /* target msc */
                       0, /* divisor */
                       0, /* remainder */
                       0, NULL);
    XFreePixmap(dpy, pixmap);

    XSync(dpy, True);
    if (_x_error_occurred)
            goto fail;

fail:
    close(device);
    return ret;
}
```